# Can a non participant party update the state in corda?

Tags: corda

Can a non participant party update the states in corda? In my use-case I need to update states by a non participant. Is that possible? Or can I declare a null-able participant in a state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Who can update a state is not defined by the `participants` field or `owner` field:

- Anyone can propose a transaction updating a state
- To become part of the ledger, it must be signed by all the required signers
- The required signers are determined by the state's contracts

It is not required for there to be any correspondence between the `participants` and the required signers. They can be completely different.

Comment: How do you propose to enforce in contract only the participants can initiates the update?

Answer (score 0):

The any `participants` of `LinearState` or the `owner` of `OwnableState` only can update the state exists on the ledger.

> Nullable participants:

You you can define the nullable `Party?` fields in State class, then in future if it has non-null value then you can add it `participants` list of a Corda state.

```
data class DummyTestState(val partyA: Party,
                          val partyB: Party?,
                          val messageNote: String,
                          override val linearId: UniqueIdentifier = UniqueIdentifier(),
                          override val participants: List<AbstractParty> = listOf(partyA)
) : LinearState
```

Comment: So can I include PartyB in to participants list ?

Comment: How can I Add a null-able Party in to participants list? after getting a value?. In this case how can I add Party B( Which is null-able initially ) into participants after getting value for party B?.

Comment: You can't add a nullable party to the participants' list. In future whenever `partyB` has non-null value then only its possible. You can write a flow to update the existing state to set a value of `partyB` and add it to the `participants` list.

Comment: e.g. `newState = state.copy(partyB=partyB,participants=listOf(partyA, partyB!!))`